# как выравнять div по центу страницы с помощью bootstrap 4

Tags: css

Чтобы он был по ширине и высоте по центру?

```css
.square{
width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: solid;
}
```

```html
<div class='square'></div>
```

Comment: а если станица со скроллом как должно быть?)

Comment: добавьте следующие стили:
margin: calc(50%-50px) auto;
Будет работать только для блока с известной высотой. При изменении высоты необходимо скорректировать функцию calc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Задать родительскому элементу display: flex (в бутстрапе 4 есть класс d-flex), а самому блоку square свойство margin: auto

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.wrapper {
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
}
.square{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: solid;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class='square'></div>
</div>
```